# I have a problem with autosaving data in VueJS, the autosave doesn't complete when I change the current note

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, autosave

so I have a problem this problem with my app. I'm not sure what is the right way to implement this autosaving feature. When you change the note's title or it's content, there is a debounce function that goes off in 2 seconds and if you change to the current note before the debounce update is complete it never updates. **Let me know if I've done a poor job of explaining or if there is something that I need to clarify, Thanks!**

Here's a video of what occurs: https://www.loom.com/share/ef5188eec3304b94b05960f403703429

And these are the important methods:

```
    updateNoteTitle(e) {
      this.noteData.title = e.target.innerText;
      this.debouncedUpdate();
    },
    updateNoteContent(e) {
      this.noteData.content = e;
      this.debouncedUpdate();
    },
    debouncedUpdate: debounce(function () {
      this.handleUpdateNote();
    }, 2000),
    async handleUpdateNote() {
      this.state = "loading";
      
      try {
        await usersCollection
          .doc(this.userId)
          .collection("notes")
          .doc(this.selectedNote.id)
          .update(this.noteData)
          .then(() => this.setStateToSaved());
      } catch (error) {
        this.state = "error";
        this.error = error;
      }
    },
    setStateToSaved() {
      this.state = "saved";
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why running every two seconds ?

To autosave the note I recommend that you add an eventListener on window closing or on changing the tab event, Like in the video provided (whatever event suits you best)

```
created () {    
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.updateNote)  
    }
```

Where your `updateNote` function is not async.

But if you really want to save on each change.
You can make a computed property that looks like this:

```
   note: {
      get() {
        return this.noteData.title;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.noteData.title = value;
        this.state= 'loading'
        usersCollection.doc(this.userId)
                       .collection("notes")
                       .doc(this.selectedNote.id)
                       .update(this.noteData)
                       .then(() => this.setStateToSaved());
      }
    },
```

And the add `v-model="note"` to your input.
Imagine the user will type 10 characters a second That's 10 calls meaning 10 saves

**EDIT:**

Add a property called isSaved.
On Note change click  `if(isSaved === false)` call your `handleUpdateNote` function.

```
updateNoteTitle(e) {
  this.noteData.title = e.target.innerText;
  this.isSaved = false;
  this.debouncedUpdate();
}
```

and in your function `setStateToSaved` add `this.isSaved = true ;`
I don't know if your side bar is a different component or not.
If it is, and you are using `$emit` to handle the Note change, then use an event listener combined with the isSaved property.

Comment: Sorry, I must have not explained it well enought, I meant, it runs 2 seconds after the user is finishes typing and if the user starts again before those 2 seconds are up it restarts those 2 seconds (I hope that makes sense), so it's not a call every second, and also when the page first loads

Comment: Now I get you. I suggest you add an event Listener that'll get triggered before changing the note and you can call your update function there too.